# Functional test for a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms

I have 2 models : Company and User. A company has many  users, and a user belong to company.
I created a nested form : when you signup, you have to create the company and the first user.

The form works like a charm but I don't really know how write tests for this. Here the functional test generated by scaffold :

```
test "should create company" do
  assert_difference('Company.count') do
    post :create, company: { city: @company.city, name: @company.name}
  end
  assert_redirected_to company_path(assigns(:company))
end
```

And here what I did in order to test the user creation :

```
test "should create company and first user" do
  assert_difference('Company.count') do
    assert_difference('User.count') do
      post :create, company: { city: @company.city, name: @company.name}, user: {name: @user.name, email: @user.email}
    end
  end
  assert_redirected_to company_path(assigns(:company))
end
```

When I run my test, the following error occurs :

```
1) Failure:
test_should_create_company_and_first_user(CompaniesControllerTest) [test/functional/companies_controller_test.rb:21]:
"User.count" didn't change by 1.
<3> expected but was
<2>.
```

I didn't find help on the Internet, so I hope someone here can do it :)

Comment: You shouldn't be posting the answer in the question. Please remove the answer from the question, answer your own question, paste the solution there, and accept that. It makes it much easier for the rest of the community to learn from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Company model

```
attr_accessible :city, :name, :users_attributes
has_many :users
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
```

User model

```
attr_accessible :email, :name
belongs_to :company
```

Companies controller test

```
test "should create company and first user" do
  assert_difference('Company.count') do
    assert_difference('User.count') do
      post :create, company: { 
        city: @company.city, 
        name: @company.name, 
        users_attributes: {
          user: {name: @user.name, email: @user.email}, 
          user: {name: @user.name, email: @user.email}
        }
      }
    end
  end
  assert_redirected_to company_path(assigns(:company))
end
```

You can test with one or more users inside the users_attributes.

Thank you @drewinglis for your help :D

Answer (score 2):

If the forms are actually nested, then you should have the user object inside the company object in the test request, like so:

```
post :create, company: { city: @company.city, name: @company.name, user: {name: @user.name, email: @user.email} }
```

Comment: Thank you ! I think you're right but I get the following error right now : `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: users` (this always in the test log, everything is ok when I fill the form). I checked and I have `attr_accessible :users_attributes` in my Company model. I also checked my User model and all attributes are accessible. Do you know if an example of functional test exists for a nested form ? Thanks again !

Comment: Ok, I found  what was wrong. I'll edit first post for a complete example. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Glad I was able to steer you in the right direction! Sorry I wasn't 100% right. :)